# ConEmu -- different color schemes for different tasks

Tags: conemu

I want to use different color schemes for different tasks in ConEmu, but I cannot figure out how. I see instructions on how to do this for different programs. However, when I check the override color palette check box, nothing happens, and the option is not retained. (What can I override it to?)

Is there a way to change the color scheme based on the task, rather than the app? (The apps are all the same, I just start in different directories, etc.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

All in the [docs](http://conemu.github.io/en/NewConsole.html#syntax).
Just add `-new_console:P:"yourpalettename"` to your shell command line in the [Task](http://conemu.github.io/en/Tasks.html)

Comment: Thank you. This is outstanding. The program works really well. I found the answer to another question also: how to create new tabs versus new windows. Please pardon my lack of patience. I had spent two hours with a ConsoleZ bug and was pretty frustrated that all my effort getting that set up was down the drain. Thanks for helping me navigate the docs.

Answer (score 9):

I've set mine so that different shells have different color theme/scheme, so that I can easily tell whether I'm in PowerShell or Bash or CMD.

Go to ConEmu's "settings".

[image: ConEmu setting window]

1. Click on Tasks
2. Select the shell/task that I want to change the scheme/theme of
3. Add `-new_console:P:"paletteName"`

   - Don't forget to escape `<` and `>` with `^`

Example: Powershell (Admin) with Powershell theme

```
powershell.exe -new_console:a:P:"^<PowerShell^>"
```

Example: Git Bash with Solarized Git theme

```
set "PATH=%ConEmuDir%\..\Git\usr\bin;%PATH%" & "%ConEmuDir%\..\Git\git-cmd.exe" --no-cd --command=%ConEmuBaseDirShort%\conemu-msys2-64.exe /usr/bin/bash.exe -l -i -new_console:P:"^<Solarized Git^>"
```

Comment: Thank you for a complete answer!